# Asus ROG Zephyrus G15 Hibernates under load

Tags: windows-10, gpu, asus-laptop

I purchased an ASUS ROG Zephyrus G15(GA502DU) a few months ago. Recently it has randomly gone into hibernation when the GPU is under load. I have not been able to diagnose any issue. I have gone through event viewer to see what may be happening in the Applications and System logs but there is nothing that stands out, only "the machine has returned from a low power state". I have spoken with the ASUS tech support who informed me to reload windows, update drivers and update BIOS. All of which I have done.

I have done some searching online and have tried just about everything I can think of.

Edit: I have also tried using a a cooling fan heat pad to no avail.

I have disabled hibernation from CMD. I have ensured the power settings are set so as to not go into hibernation or any type of sleep mode. I believe this may be an overheating issue but am unsure.

Any help would be appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the GPU was overheating. It would reach temps around 95C and would hibernate to protect itself. This was primarily with the lid closed. Some solutions I had found were to either run with the lid open, or remove some of the plastic vent covers from the underside.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, when I have the lid closed, G15 will randomly hibernation if it's under load.

the only solution right now is to keep your lid open. I think.